# how to change data Automatically not using open the webpage for Per hour 

Tags: javascript, python, google-app-engine

i seem like this :

```
class myData(db.Model):
    today= db.DateTimeProperty()
```

how to set 'today' to now time for Per hour ,not using open the webpage ?

thanks

Comment: This question needs to be changed to make a little more sense. Clarification is required where you mention Per hour. Also, clarification is required where you mention not opening the webpage. When you create a new MyData, the today field will be set to the datetime of instantiation. auto_now_add=True enforces this creation datetime - it can not be changed.

Comment: thanks, i delete the auto_now_add=True

Comment: I can't understand what you're asking.

Comment: I believe he wants to have a record in the datastore that tells him what today is, and gets updated every hour. So he wants a task that starts up every hour and updates the record. I'm not sure why he needs this, or why he doesn't just check the time in his app, but that's at least what I think he's asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a [Task Queue](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/).